# Understanding better Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I read documentation about JQuery.ajax but I have some questions.

From here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

The data sent and received is automatically with Json? The code inside ajax method `$.ajax` is Jquery code or Ajax code? Then when I'm writing code inside ajax I'm writing Jquery code with ajax method or ajax code with JQuery help?

Comment: All you're ever writing is JavaScript, I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically with Json code" if you mean.. is it automatically turned into json, you can pass a javascript object to it yes and it will be turned to json

Comment: @ I mean that if I don't specify anything about Json, alone is sending and returning something with Json? Well im using javascript ever is used Jquery then this means that all  I writing is Jquery code with ajax method nothing code about ajax.

Comment: From that page you linked:: data

Type: PlainObject or String or Array

Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Comment: Ajax is just a function, function takes sets of arguments of different type, JSON object, string, ets. All that you are writing is JavaScript, JQuery is a framework written to easy work of JavaScript, browser only understand javaScript, that's all we write.

Comment: ok ty guys, you helped so much to undertand all this better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your writing is javascript like Dale said in the comments.

Lets say you have a javascript object and you want to post that to your back end using ajax. You'd have to use JSON.stringify() to make it into a JSON string as this method serializes the javascript object or array or whatever you're sending back into a JSON string which the back end can read and understand.

JSON.parse parses a string into a javascript object. so e.g if you have
var text = '{ "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}';
you can use 
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
to parse it into a javascript object

Thats how I use it with asp.net as a backend.

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

if you asking about content type, you can specify that in the object you passed to the $.ajax.for example if you want to send and receive json set it like this :

```
jQuery.ajax({
'type': 'POST',
'url': url,
'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'data': JSON.stringify(data),
'dataType': 'json'
});
```

and about the type of jquery ajax: it's a wrapper for XMLHttpRequest of pure javascript.